# GraphLab Installation fails with unknown error

Tags: python, graphlab

I tried installing GraphLab Create through pip. Zipped through the steps until the final step stopped me in my tracks.
The final command:

```
pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir https://get.dato.com/GraphLab-Create/1.7.1/email@gmail.com/*******license key****/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz
```

This gives the following output:

```
Collecting https://get.dato.com/GraphLab-Create/1.7.1/***************@gmail.com/********license***********/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz   Downloading https://get.dato.com/GraphLab-Create/1.7.1/***************@gmail.com/*******license*************/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz Collecting graphlab-create>=1.7.1 (from GraphLab-Create-License==1.7.1)   Downloading GraphLab_Create-1.7.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl (45.0MB) Requirement already up-to-date: boto==2.33.0 in c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from graphlab-create>=1.7.1->GraphLab-Create-License==1.7.1) Requirement already up-to-date: prettytable==0.7.2 in c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from graphlab-create>=1.7.1->GraphLab-Create-License==1.7.1) Requirement already up-to-date: decorator==3.4.0 in c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from graphlab-create>=1.7.1->GraphLab-Create-License==1.7.1) Requirement already up-to-date: librato-metrics==0.4.9 in c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from graphlab-create>=1.7.1->GraphLab-Create-License==1.7.1) Requirement already up-to-date: awscli==1.6.2 in c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from graphlab-create>=1.7.1->GraphLab-Create-License==1.7.1) Requirement already up-to-date: multipledispatch>=0.4.7 in c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from graphlab-create>=1.7.1->GraphLab-Create-License==1.7.1) Collecting sseclient==0.0.8 (from graphlab-create>=1.7.1->GraphLab-Create-License==1.7.1)   Downloading sseclient-0.0.8.tar.gz Collecting certifi==2015.04.28 (from graphlab-create>=1.7.1->GraphLab-Create-License==1.7.1)   Downloading certifi-2015.04.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (373kB) Requirement already up-to-date: requests==2.3.0 in c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from graphlab-create>=1.7.1->GraphLab-Create-License==1.7.1) Requirement already up-to-date: mixpanel-py==3.1.1 in c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from graphlab-create>=1.7.1->GraphLab-Create-License==1.7.1) Requirement already up-to-date: tornado==4.1 in c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from graphlab-create>=1.7.1->GraphLab-Create-License==1.7.1) Requirement already up-to-date: six in c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from librato-metrics==0.4.9->graphlab-create>=1.7.1->GraphLab-Create-License==1.7.1) Requirement already up-to-date: rsa==3.1.2 in c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from awscli==1.6.2->graphlab-create>=1.7.1->GraphLab-Create-License==1.7.1) Requirement already up-to-date: botocore<0.74.0,>=0.73.0 in c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from awscli==1.6.2->graphlab-create>=1.7.1->GraphLab-Create-License==1.7.1) Requirement already up-to-date: docutils>=0.10 in c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from awscli==1.6.2->graphlab-create>=1.7.1->GraphLab-Create-License==1.7.1) Requirement already up-to-date: colorama==0.2.5 in c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from awscli==1.6.2->graphlab-create>=1.7.1->GraphLab-Create-License==1.7.1) Requirement already up-to-date: bcdoc<0.13.0,>=0.12.0 in c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from awscli==1.6.2->graphlab-create>=1.7.1->GraphLab-Create-License==1.7.1) Requirement already up-to-date: backports.ssl-match-hostname in c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from tornado==4.1->graphlab-create>=1.7.1->GraphLab-Create-License==1.7.1) Requirement already up-to-date: pyasn1>=0.1.3 in c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from rsa==3.1.2->awscli==1.6.2->graphlab-create>=1.7.1->GraphLab-Create-License==1.7.1) Requirement already up-to-date: jmespath==0.5.0 in c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from botocore<0.74.0,>=0.73.0->awscli==1.6.2->graphlab-create>=1.7.1->GraphLab-Create-License==1.7.1) Requirement already up-to-date: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from botocore<0.74.0,>=0.73.0->awscli==1.6.2->graphlab-create>=1.7.1->GraphLab-Create-License==1.7.1) Installing collected packages: sseclient, certifi, graphlab-create, GraphLab-Create-License   Running setup.py install for sseclient   Found existing installation: certifi 2015.11.20.1
    Uninstalling certifi-2015.11.20.1:
      Successfully uninstalled certifi-2015.11.20.1   Running setup.py install for GraphLab-Create-License
    Complete output from command C:\Anaconda2\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\abhish~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-7mleag-build\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\abhish~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-bv7hrn-record\install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running install_egg_info
    running egg_info
    writing requirements to GraphLab_Create_License.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing GraphLab_Create_License.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to GraphLab_Create_License.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to GraphLab_Create_License.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found
    reading manifest file 'GraphLab_Create_License.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'GraphLab_Create_License.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    Copying GraphLab_Create_License.egg-info to C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\GraphLab_Create_License-1.7.1-py2.7.egg-info
    running install_scripts
    writing list of installed files to 'c:\users\abhish~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-bv7hrn-record\install-record.txt'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\abhish~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-7mleag-build\setup.py", line 61, in <module>
        cmdclass=dict(install=SetLicense)
      File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\abhish~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-7mleag-build\setup.py", line 41, in run
        config.read(config_filename)
      File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 305, in read
        self._read(fp, filename)
      File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 512, in _read
        raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
    ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
    file: C:\Users\abhish**\.graphlab\config, line: 1
    '\x00\***lots of hex code***x00'

    ----------------------------------------
```

What is wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The config file seems corrupted, possibly due to a previous failed installation; it should always contain section headers.

Try deleting the config file (`C:\Users\abhish**\.graphlab\config`) and re-installing, which will re-create it.